# Can't delete and erase object pointer on a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, object, vector, delete-operator

I need to delete and erase object pointer on a vector.
I see this question [Should we delete before or after erase for an pointer in the vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733081/should-we-delete-before-or-after-erase-for-an-pointer-in-the-vector) but I can't erase after delete object pointer.

How to fix it? Here my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
    class bar
    {
    public:
        Foo &_owner;
        int _id;
        bar(Foo &owner,int id) : _id(id), _owner(owner){}
        void remove()
        {
            for(vector<bar*>::iterator it=_owner.vbar.begin();it<_owner.vbar.end();it++)
            {
                if((*it)->_id == _id)
                {
                    //delete object pointer
                    delete * it;

                    //remove element
                    it = _owner.vbar.erase(it); // error on this line.
                }
            }
        }
    };
    vector<bar*> vbar;
    Foo()
    {
        // add 10 elements
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            vbar.push_back(new bar(*this ,i));

        // remove element at 3
        vbar.at(3)->remove();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Foo foo;
    return 0;
}
```

---

***[Edited]***
I fixed this by delete object pointer from outside Bar class(delete on Foo class)
by adding no longer use bar id to vector on Foo class like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
    class bar
    {
    public:
        Foo &_owner;
        int _id;
        bar(Foo &owner,int id) : _id(id), _owner(owner) {}
        void remove()
        {
            _owner.removeId = _id;
            _owner.removeHelper();
        }
    };
    vector<bar*> vbar;
    int removeId;
    Foo()
    {
        removeId = -1;

        // add 10 elements
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
            vbar.push_back(new bar(*this ,i));

        // remove element at 3
        vbar.at(3)->remove();
    }
    void removeHelper()
    {
        for(vector<bar*>::iterator it=vbar.begin(); it<vbar.end(); it++)
        {
            if((*it)->_id == removeId)
            {
                //delete object pointer
                delete * it;

                //remove element
                it = vbar.erase(it);
                break;
            }
        }
        removeId = -1;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Foo foo;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is hidden here

```
//delete object pointer
delete * it;
```

which in this case is the equivalent of `delete this`.

After that, using any part of the current object is undefined behavior. The next round of the loop is *not* going to work.